# gtest and MinGW linkage

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, googletest, linkage

I've made a simple main to check if gtest was correctly linked and got "undefined reference" errors. The first line in the main function throws an undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
     return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I have successfully built a gtest Code::Block project with the help of cmake and without the pthread library. Then, I compiled everything with MinGW. I took the libgtest.a libgmock.a and linked them in my Code::Block project with no problems. I also specified the include directories and the binary directories. Is it possible that I need to include gtest_main.a too?

The build log (I added "..." to hide long chains of folders):

> "obj\Debug gtest\MainTest.o" -lsfml-graphics-s-d -lsfml-window-s-d -lsfml-network-s-d -lsfml-audio-s-d -lsfml-system-s-d -lglew -lgtest -lgmock -lws2_32 -lopenal32 -lsndfile -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lfreetype -ljpeg -lglu32 -lopengl32 
>   obj\Debug gtest\MainTest.o: In function `main': 
>   D:/.../Templates/SFML 2_2 BasicScene/MainTest.cpp:5: undefined reference to`testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)' 
>   obj\Debug gtest\MainTest.o: In function `Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv': 
>   D:/.../googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:2237: undefined reference to`testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()' 
>   D:/.../googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:2237: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'

Comment: To get a linkage failure explained it is essential that you provide
the compiler commandline that executes the failing linkage, as well
as the error messages. Post this information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it! It was tricky: as I am using Windows 7 and installed multiple compilers (3 versions of MinGW and 2 of TDM), my PATH got all mixed up. When I was using cmake-gui 3.3, I was using the default compiler, which was MinGW 4.7 when I installed Code::Blocks. After installing all the compilers mentionned above, the default compiler path changed for a higher version of MinGW. Linking with a library that was compiled with a newer version of MinGW didn't cause the library to not be found, but instead caused linking errors.

In conclusion, I was using two differents versions of the same compiler.